# remove table row and ajax call

Tags: jquery

I want to remove remove table row from table and subsequently remove the item from database also.

The html generated is from ajax call at page load that gets the html from the php file.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "http://localhost/zabjournal/author/submit/progress",
    data: {returnSubmissions:1},
    success: function(response) {
            $('#activeSubmissions').html(response);
    }
});
```

In that PHP file I have define like this

```
$str = '<table class="zebra-striped">';
$i=1;
foreach ( $arr as $article)
{
        $str.= "<tr id=".$article->article_id.">
        <td>".$i."</td>
        <td>".$article->first_name." ".$article->last_name."</td>
        <td>".$article->title."</td>
        <td>".$article->date_submitted."</td>
        <td>
            <a class='btn primary'>View</a>
            <a class='btn'>Edit</a>
            <a class='btn error'>Delete</a></td>
        </td>
        </tr>";
    $i++;           
}
$str.='</tbody></table>';

echo $str;
```

Its my jQuery function to remove the table row

```
    $('a.btn error').click(function(){
    alert('az'); //alert wasnt even called
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost/zabjournal/author/submit/progress",
            data: {article_id:id},
            success: function(response) {
             alert(id);
            }
        });
    });
```

But when I click the delete button, there is no action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with your selector, you are searching a tag "error" inside a tag "a" which has class "btn".

Try replacing :

```
$('a.btn error')
```

by :

```
$('a.btn.error')
```

In this case you will correctly search a tag "a" with both classes "btn" and "error".

Comment: Its still not being called, I have checked from my code, I dont know what is causing this.

Comment: Have you checked your generated html table ? Can you show us the result ?

Edit : Oh, just found another mistake in your code : "$str.='</tbody></table>';" => You are closing "tbody" which is not opened before in your code.

Comment: well that must have been mistake in formatting code here, but the html is fine on notepad++

Comment: Also I am placing the table in a div element

Comment: So is your alert('az') called with all remarks i did ?
i tried a [simple example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mbcBj/) and it works for me

Comment: Interestingly enough, when I put hard code the table HTML and not from the ajax call, then it works. Otherwise, the anchor tag is not being called

Comment: That's what i guess, just inspect the html generated by your server and you should find the issue

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9372/discussion-between-asdgfas-sagas-and-mordhak)

Comment: Finally, the issue was about two things : html generated by server side was incorrect and jQuery code was executed before server call was returned (and then success was called).